# IBM MobileFirst - Properties files

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a MobileFirst APP, calling three web services, when I call these Web services, using an IP (localhost), but when I connect my mobile PC have to use another IP calls, and then have to use other production.

To make it easy and comfortable setup, as I can do in MobileFirst, it is the worklight.properties file?

Greetings and thank you,

Comment: other thing, and it is possible to access a variable worklight.properties and access it from a js file?

Answer (score 1):

That's some crazy English going on there...

If your question is really "can I save the web service IP address (that I am using in my adapter XML file) in a variable in worklight.properties, so that different IPs will be used for my adapters in different environments (DEV, QA, PROD)" - yes.

I believe that in this case [JNDI properties will not help](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_using_JNDI_lookup_to_override_WL_properties.html), but you could do the following.

You will need to create a different copy of worklight.properties per the environment you want to test at, and in each file [add custom properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_declaring_using_app_specific_config_props.html), for example:

myWebServiceIP=192.168.123.1 (you'll need to change this value per file)

Then in the adapter XML file, use it like this:

```
<domain>${myWebServiceIP}</domain>
```

Comment: Sincere applogies for my terrible level of english. I will try to enhance my level for future queries Thanks for the prompt answer. I will look into it and let u know about it
 Thanks